# How to combine result of two each iterators into one JSON array of objects

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am trying to produce the following JSON structure:

```
"events": [
        {
            "start_date": {
                "year": "602"
            },  
            "end_date": {
                "year":"629"
            },
            "media": {
                "url": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman-Persian_Wars"
            },
            "background": {
        "opacity":"50",
                "url": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a2/HumiliationValerianusHolbein.jpg"
            },
            "text": {
                "headline": "Last great Roman-Persian War.",
                "text": "Long conflict leaves both empires exhausted and unable to cope with the newly united Arab armies under Islam in the 630s"
            }
        },
    {
    "start_date": {
        "year": "604"
    },
    "end_date": {
        "year": "609"
    },
    "media": {
        "url": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Canal_(China)"
    },
    "background": {
"opacity":"50",
        "url": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ad/Sui_Wendi_Tang.jpg"
    },
    "text": {
        "headline": "Grand Canal in China is fully completed",
        "text": "Its main role throughout its history was the transport of grain to the capital."
    }
}
```

There are about 25 objects within the events array, but to make this shorter I've only included two here.

For the moment I'm only trying to create the "sub-objects" of background and text within the master object.

I am scraping this Wikipedia page with Node and the request and cheerio libraries: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_the_Middle_Ages

The first part of my code (below) uses the request library to gather together all the links to other pages from the main Wikipedia "landing page":

```
request(landingPage, function (err, response, body) {
    var $ = cheerio.load(body);
    var absoluteLinks = [];

// GET REMOTE PAGE LINKS FOR IMAGES:
    // eq(1) = 7th Century Table
    $('.wikitable').eq(1).find('tr').each(function() {
        var $link = $(this).find('td').eq(2).find('a').eq(0).attr('href');
        if ( $link != undefined || $link != null ) {
          absoluteLinks.push("https://en.wikipedia.org" + $link);
        }
    });
    getRemoteImages(absoluteLinks);
 });
```

The second part uses Promise.all in order to ensure that the array of image urls is constructed in the same order as the array of scraped page urls:

```
function getRemoteImages(absoluteLinks) {
    Promise.all(absoluteLinks.map (function (a) {
     return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
       request(a, function(err, response, body) {
         if (err) { return reject(err); }
         $ = cheerio.load(body);
         var $thumbImg = $('.infobox').find('img').eq(0).attr('src');
         // To do: make full size image
         $thumbImg = "https:" + $thumbImg;
          resolve({ thumbImg: $thumbImg });
       });
     });
    })).then(function (result) {
      cleanImages(result);
    }).catch(function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    });
}
```

The third part of the code is the bit I'm struggling with:

```
function buildTextSection(result) {

    request(landingPage, function (err, response, body) {
      var data = { "events": [] };

      $ = cheerio.load(body);
      $('.wikitable').eq(1).find('tr').each(function() {
        var evObj = {};
          var $headline = $(this).find('td').eq(2).html();
          var $text = $(this).find('td').eq(3).text();
          evObj.text = {"headline": $headline, "text": $text };

          data.events.push(evObj);
      }); // end each
      console.log(data.events.length);
      buildImageSection(data, result);
    });
  }

  function buildImageSection(data, result) {

    result.forEach(function(obj) {
      data.events.background = {"opacity": "50", "url": obj.thumbImg };
      console.log(data);
      // console.log(data.events);
    }); // end forEach
  }
```

I can't find a way integrate the two different each iterators (one gathering the text data from the "local" landing page, and the other gathering the image urls from each "remote" Wikipedia destination page).

My last attempt (of many) generates this output when I run the file in the terminal with console.log(data);

```
{ events: 
   [ { text: [Object] },
     { text: [Object] },
     { text: [Object] },
     { text: [Object] },
     { text: [Object] },
     { text: [Object] },
     { text: [Object] },
     { text: [Object] },
     { text: [Object] },
     { text: [Object] },
     { text: [Object] },
     { text: [Object] },
     { text: [Object] },
     { text: [Object] },
     { text: [Object] },
     { text: [Object] },
     { text: [Object] },
     { text: [Object] },
     { text: [Object] },
     { text: [Object] },
     { text: [Object] },
     { text: [Object] },
     { text: [Object] },
     { text: [Object] },
     { text: [Object] },
     background: { opacity: '50',
       url: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/10/History_of_Korea-Inter-country_Age-830_CE.gif/220px-History_of_Korea-Inter-country_Age-830_CE.gif' } ] }
```

How can I solve this problem? I've completely run out of ideas now! Thanks!

Comment: How is the original data structure and what would the desired output? Can you provide us a simple example?

Comment: Hi Diego, the desired output is the first JSON structure I provided - the one I'm trying to produce.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for the background property part:

in `buildImageSection`, you overwrite in each loop the same `background` property. If you are sure that `data.events` and `results` are in same order (and have same number of elements), you can acces by numeric index:

```
function buildImageSection(data, result) {

    var index = 0;

    result.forEach(function(obj) {
      //data.events.background = {"opacity": "50", "url": obj.thumbImg };
      data.events[index].background = {"opacity": "50", "url": obj.thumbImg };

      index++;

      console.log(data);
      // console.log(data.events);
    }); // end forEach
}
```

i can elaborate if you have problems with other parts, but try to be precise in your questions please ;)

**EDIT for the update**: unfortunately, this needs some changes if they don't have the same length. You'll need some way to identify the rows to find them back. To stay simple, i will only consider that you parse one table at a time (i see the wiki splits them by centuries in different tables). If you want to get all the tabless, you will need another way to track the table like with the row. this would be done using associative arrays for example, with a key formatted as such `table1row4`

fortunately, you can identify rows index with jquery (i commented all to highlight the changes made):

```
/*request(landingPage, function (err, response, body) {
    var $ = cheerio.load(body);
    var absoluteLinks = {};

    // GET REMOTE PAGE LINKS FOR IMAGES:
    // eq(1) = 7th Century Table
    $('.wikitable').eq(1).find('tr').each(function() {
        var $link = $(this).find('td').eq(2).find('a').eq(0).attr('href');
        if ( $link != undefined || $link != null ) {*/

          //i show here the simpler method, using the tr index to be sure that numeric
          //indexes match, but this won't work if you wan to store multiple
          //tables in the same array
          absoluteLink[$(this).index()] = "https://en.wikipedia.org" + $link;

        /*}
    });
    getRemoteImages(absoluteLinks);
});*/
```

then for the rest, you want to sort the array the same way:

```
/*function buildTextSection(result) {

    request(landingPage, function (err, response, body) {
      var data = { "events": [] };

      $ = cheerio.load(body);
      $('.wikitable').eq(1).find('tr').each(function() {
        var evObj = {};
          var $headline = $(this).find('td').eq(2).html();
          var $text = $(this).find('td').eq(3).text();
          evObj.text = {"headline": $headline, "text": $text };*/

          //the tr index again
          data.events[$(this).index()] = evObj;


      /*}); // end each
      console.log(data.events.length);
      buildImageSection(data, result);
    });
}*/
```

finally, you have to test the existence of the image in the array before you fill it (you have to proceed the other way round and loop on data.events, because javascript is not good with arrays with numeric index and "holes" in it)

```
function buildImageSection(data, result) {

    var index = 0;

    data.events.forEach(function(obj) {
      if(result[index]){
          obj.background = {"opacity": "50", "url": result[index].thumbImg };
      }else{
          //do we need to set a background property if no image?
      }

      index++;

      console.log(data);
      // console.log(data.events);
    }); // end forEach
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is pretty much exactly what I wanted! There is not exactly the same number of elements as not every event object has an image associated with it. But this is a limitation with the data. Is there any way to "dynamically add" the images by key (instead of index) or is this not possible?

Comment: Just a small tweak for anyone in future reading this - you will want to put the console.log outside the foreach loop (otherwise massive data duplication happens), and use JSON.stringify method so it's more readable in terminal/console: console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 4));